# Tuscan tree identification

Tags: identification, trees

These sparsely branched trees appear all over northern Tuscany, is anyone able to help identify them?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From this distance its impossible to see the foliage clearly, but I'm willing to bet they're Italian Stone Pines, or Pinus pinea, one of Italy's iconic trees, also sometimes known as Parasol Pine. The ones in  your photo have been pruned back so the crowns are smaller than they normally would be, and I must say they look extremely attractive, it's been very well done; there are some similar to these in shape in Rome. Photo in the link below

http://dryades.units.it/torlonia/?procedure=taxon_page&id=164&num=2918

It's in Italian, but that won't affect the image, and Google will translate the text if you want to read it anyway.